Access denied to MS Access File in C:ProgramFiles(86) folder
I am working on a VB.Net 2022 Windows Application and I am keeping a .mdb access database file in the bin folder and I created the setup of the application. After installation, the access database is in the C:\ProgramFiles(86)\MyApplication\Setup folder along with the executable file. Since we are working in a company where installation of any files in the company laptop needs admin permission access. After installation, when trying to double click on the app icon on desktop, I am getting following error message.
 Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Financial Reporting\Financial Reporting.mdb' is denied.




[![Access denied][1]][1]

After running the application as administrator and giving user name and password of admin, it works. But my concern is how we can avoid this message and run with out admin access.
In my application, I using the below connection string to access the MS Access database is like below. But this below code is in another window. Not in the frmMain_Load() event.
      DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString =
        "Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;" +
        "Data Source='" + Application.ExecutablePath.Replace(".exe", ".mdb") + "';" +
        "Password=;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;" +
        "Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';" +
        "Jet OLEDB:System database=;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;" +
        "Extended Properties=;" +
        "Mode=Share Deny None;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:New Database Password=;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;" +
        "User ID=Admin;" +
        "Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False"

But in the frmMain_Load() event, we have the below file checking.
       '
    If File.Exists(Application.ExecutablePath.Replace(".exe", ".mdb")) Then
        File.Delete(Application.ExecutablePath.Replace(".exe", ".mdb"))
    End If

But how do we avoid the error message that shown when double clicking the application icon ???

Normal user can't delete files on programfiles and other system paths. You either need to redesign your logic (no deletion of mdb) or set it up in appdata folder.

Maybe you should look at using ClickOnce to deploy your app, which is designed not to require admin permissions. That will create a proper installer for your app but not use the standard Program Files folder.

The following may be of interest: Environment.SpecialFolder Enum

There is a ProgramData folder which is designed for this kind of use.
